# Erro O driver não pode estabelecer uma conexão segura com o SQL Server usando a criptografia SSL com SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-jpa, sql-server-2005

Pessoal estou tentando conectar com o Banco Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5324.00 (X64) utilizando o Spring boot e sempre ocorre o erro abaixo:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)

2021-11-17 11:16:38.677  INFO 9512 --- [           main] b.c.v.C.CopyBDApplication : Starting CopyDBApplication using Java 1.8.0_281 on JULIANO-PC with PID 9512 (C:\Intellij\CopyBD\build\classes\java\main started by JULIANO in C:\Intellij\CopyBD)
2021-11-17 11:16:38.684  INFO 9512 --- [           main] b.c.v.C.CopyBDApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-17 11:16:40.127  INFO 9512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-17 11:16:40.210  INFO 9512 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 30 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-17 11:16:50.549  INFO 9512 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-17 11:16:56.179 ERROR 9512 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: O driver n�o p�de estabelecer uma conex�o segura com o SQL Server usando a criptografia SSL. Erro: "Unexpected rethrowing".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3206) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1916) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2760) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2418) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2265) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:881) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) [spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) [spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) [spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330) [spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:184) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:143) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:103) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:95) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at br.com.vexia.CopyDB.CopyDBApplication.main(CopyDB.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected rethrowing
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:325) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1279) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1824) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: O SQL Server n�o retornou uma resposta. A conex�o foi fechada. ClientConnectionId:04fdca83-5cd1-4c43-99ff-30ea3aafa300
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:806) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:856) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:849) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1019) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:1009) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:475) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:469) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:159) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Para testes criei um projeto limpo apenas com as configurações de banco e as dependências abaixo:

**build.gradle**

```
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.6'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }
    
    group = 'br.com.juliano'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    }
    
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://BDSQL2005;databaseName=teste
    spring.datasource.username=juliano
    spring.datasource.password=Juliano123
```

**Testes executados:**

**1 - Conectar no banco via IDE SQL Server Management Studio v18.8**

Para descartar algum problema de rede foi efetuado a conexão atraves da IDE e a conexão foi fechada com sucesso.

**2 - Ajuste dos parâmetros na url de conexão spring.datasource.url**

Nenhuma das opções abaixo conectou com sucesso. sempre apresentando o mesmo erro

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://BDSQL2005;databaseName=teste

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://BDSQL2005;databaseName=teste;encrypt=false;

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://BDSQL2005;databaseName=teste;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://BDSQL2005;databaseName=teste;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false

**3 - Utilizar dependências mais antigas**

Nenhuma das opções abaixo conectou com sucesso. sempre apresentando o mesmo erro

implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc:4.2'

implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc:3.0'

implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc42

implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:unknown'

**4 - Mudança de Versão do Java**

Utilizado o Java 8 e Java 11. Ambos sem sucesso

**5 - Subir uma versão mais atual do SQL Server no Docker**
Com este teste a conexão foi fechado com sucesso. Por conta disso imagino que seja algo no Banco de dados, talvez incompatibilidade por ser uma versão antiga. Porem não encontrei nada.

Caso alguém consiga me dar um luz, eu agradeço.

Comment: SQL 2005? isso é beeeemmmm velho! :)  pro conta disso talvez seja o problema da versão de SSL, mais especificamente o `TLS`. Acho no SQL 2005 deve ser a versão 1 ainda, veja se teu driver não estuando uma versão superior (1.2, 2.x etc)

Comment: Nem me fale. esse clientes que não atualizam os ambientes é só dor de cabeça. Você sabe se tem como informar essa versão na connection ? tentei usar o sslProtocol=TLSv1, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema e consegui resolve habilitando o , TLSv1, TLSv1.1

mensagem de erro que apresentava no meu caso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no exemplo estou usando o [graalvm](https://www.graalvm.org) mas o procedimento é o mesmo pra qualquer jdk.

localize o arquivo java.security no meu caso ele estava no caminho:

```
.../graalvm-ce-java11-21.3.0/Contents/Home/conf/security/java.security
```

localize a variável:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=
```

remova o TLSv1, TLSv1.1:

no meu caso ficou assim:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

salve o arquivo e pronto.

caso não funcione ou deseje uma outra alternativa segue referencia:
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/opensource/tls-1-0-1-1-changes-in-openjdk-and-amazon-corretto/

Espero ter ajudado!

t+